# how to perform "git status" across many submodules

Tags: git, status, git-submodules

I have a git repository with several submodules. When I perform a `git status` in the parent module it only shows me changes at that level, and I need to `cd` into each submodule and perform `git status` separately in each module. Is there a better way of doing this so that I can perform `git status` at the top level and see the changes across all submodules?

My `git --version` returns:

> git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git status && echo'
```

You could turn this into a Git alias to avoid having to type it out each time.

Comment: Good effort. This is close to what I need, it lists the changes in each subrepository, although there are no newlines to separate the filenames that have changes, although each submodule is correctly separated by a newline. If you can make it separate the filenames, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, since `submodule foreach` already indicates when it enters each submodule, you can probably omit the path echo which will fix the newlines problem. Here, I'll edit it.

Answer (score -1):

git do not know anything about submodules. it just keep the dir tree as a whole repository. a correctly installed git copy, when you run "git status" it should show all changes to the repository.
but if your submodules belongs to different repositories, there is no official way to show all changes.(maybe write some script)